# express-rate-limit is bloking for all ip

Tags: node.js, express

I have use express-rate-limit but it didn't work as expected. It works first time only. After that it blocks all ip address.Once it block an ip  then it shows error msg for every request.

I am using it on ubuntu server.

```
    const loginLimiter = rateLimit({
      windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 minute window
      max: 15, // start blocking after 15 requests
      message:
        "Too many attampts, you have been blocked"
    });

router.post("/login",loginLimiter, users.signin);
```

Comment: check https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/92

Comment: I stuck at last point. Every time i am getting same ip address for diffrent request ie. 127.0.0.1. It should be the request ip but it's not.  keyGenerator: function (req /*, res*/) {
          console.log('requidiid',req.ip); //shows 127.0.0.1 for every reqest
          return req.ip;
      }

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? as nginx ?

Comment: yes i am using nginx as proxy

Comment: I got this working. I have use proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; in nginx config file and then req.headers['x-real-ip']  is giving me actual ip
and it's working.

Comment: pls does anyone know how to achieve same in Apache

Answer (score 1):

if you are using nginx proxy (proxy_pass), the client IP on the app request will be the server IP instead of getting the actual client IP. That's why express-rate-limit blocks all requests even if the clients are different.

so you need to expose the actual client IP. Add this config to your nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

example:

```
location /api {
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://123.......;
}
```